# Installing September CU in SP 2010 Causes Site to Load Slowly

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, patching, page-load

I installed Microsoft's September CU (KB 3115473) in my SP 2010 Dev and Disaster Recovery  Farms. All were successful and no errors.

The only issue I have is that after the installation, whenever I open the root site in my DR environment, it takes a little over a minute for the page to load.

I tested in my Dev environment the same thing and it's intermittent. There's times when it takes a minute and sometimes it takes a few seconds.

However, in my DR environment I can say that it takes about a minute or so consistently.

Is there something wrong under the hood? What can I check to see the cause?

I know this can be a pain because there were no errors during installation nor errors on the page. It just takes a little longer than what I'm comfortable with.

Comment: Are the Application Pool unloading the app domain between the times you've tried it? It is normal for the first request when the app domain spins up to take quite some time due to the JIT'ing process of the SharePoint binaries.

Answer (score 0):

CU Installation is two Step process.

1. 1st you have to install the Updates(binaries) on all servers in the farm
2. Now you have to run the SharePoint Config Wizard on all server one by one.

I had experience when we did not run the config wizard and our sites load slow.

But if you already run the config wizard, then you clear the Config Cache on all SharePoint server.

Comment: I looked at the article where it shows how to clear the config cache. I guess my question is do I have to perform those steps on ALL servers in the farm?

Comment: Yes, you should do